# How to increment printf format php variable

Tags: php, variables, printf

On my WordPress blog I'm trying to give specific id's to sidebar widgets. I'd like to just give them a simple incrementing ID for example `id="sidebar-box-" . $i` where i is the incrementing variable.

I have code that I got from [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar), which can give it a specific id but I'd like more control over the id for style purposes and to keep my css following the same pattern. The code I have currently looks like this:

```
function custom_sidebar() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Blog Sidebar',
        'id'            => 'blog_sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="sb-box-%d" class="sidebar-box">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3>',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>',
    ) );
}
```

But this code gives me an id like this: `decent_comments_widget-2`. My understanding is that the %1 is saying use the first parameter of the printf function like a string based on [what I've read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php). I can't understand what the $s part is and I'm not even sure where it's getting the first parameter from since the register sidebar function is only being passed an array as its first parameter. What is the correct way to just make a simple id with an incrementing variable at the end? Any help in understanding variables in this format is also welcome. Thanks!

**EDIT:** I changed the id value from "sb-box-%1$s" to "sb-box-%d" but now I only get "sb-box-0" printed over and over again for each 'sidebar-box' class div in the sidebar. I can't figure out the right place to set the variable.

Comment: The `1$` can be used for argument swapping, check [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#example-5473) for more information.

Comment: @tomudding, it is not the `$s`, but `1$`. `s` part just indicates string part.

Comment: @AlexBlex whoops, my bad, I copied the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd use `%s` (or something else) to indicate you want to have a string to be placed there when you are using `sprintf()`.

But when you have multiple (different) conversion specifications (`%_`) you need to have the arguments that you pass into `sprintf()` in the same order as they are in your format string or you can specify the order they need to be in. Else the string might not look like you had expected.

That can be done very easily by using `n$` (as @AlexBlex said) where `n` is the nth argument.

**Example:**
I have the string `I am buying %d %s.` (which can be `I am buying 2 tomatoes.`) but I want my sprintf() function to be like this `sprintf($format, $item, $amount);`.
That won't be possible with my current string. By adding 1$ between `%` and `s` I can specify that that placeholder will be the first argument and `$2` for `%d` to specify that that will be the second argument.
What I get is this:

```
$item = "tomatoes";
$amount = 314;
$format = "I am buying %2$d %1$s.";
echo sprintf($format, $item, $amount);

// I am buying 314 tomatoes.
```

The documentation on [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#example-5472) has some more information about argument swapping.

**id="sidebar-box-" . $i**
You want to increment a part of the id of the div, I'd suggest you change the value of your `before_widget` array key to `<div id="side-barbox-%d" class="sidebar-box">` this way you can easily increment the integer and then pass this through `sprintf()`.

Comment: I believe the question was how to do it in wordpress, which uses sprintf to process the sidebar array in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer! Using "sidebar-box-%d" gives me a zero in the name every time. I think this will work but I just haven't set the variable in the correct place. Where is the appropriate place to set the variable?

Comment: @DigitalBrent Is your variable a string (like `$var = "2";`)? Because then you have to use `%s` instead of `%d` because it is used for a (signed) decimal number and `sprintf()` will insert a `0` instead of the actual number.

Comment: no I've tried setting the variable several times in different places in the function on my original question, but it only breaks the sidebar code :(

Comment: Does it have to be set somewhere else in the functions.php file?

Comment: Can you update your question with the current code you have? I need to see the actual code (which may not work) before I am able to help you.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your code. Take a look at it and decide if it is what you want else just ask :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138133/discussion-between-tomudding-and-digital-brent).